# colorbox border not displaying properly

Tags: jquery, colorbox

My colorbox border isn't showing up correctly:

http://www.mmrempen.com/test/test.html

(Click one of the image strips and videos will pop up)

As you can see, the border shows up on the top and left, but not on the bottom or right. I tried changing the border settings in the css file, but it didn't help.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this css fix

For the div id cboxLoadedContent

```
#cboxLoadedContent {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 5px solid #000000;
    height: 384px;
    width: 689px;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, no dice. Am I supposed to put that in the colorbox.css, or on the  page itself?

Answer (score 0):

check the image paths in colorbox css....

as u need to put '../' if ur page is outside or as per the folder structure...

-
hope will help u.  --- (iminfo.in)